# New to python fabric and not able to run basic code

Tags: python, fabric

I have a basic code which doesn't run:

```
def hello():
    print("uptime")
```

When I run the following command in terminal `fab hello`

I get this error:

> No idea what 'hello' is!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the new fabric task method (as discussed here - http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/tasks.html) is to use the @task decorator. The equivalent example for your code is:

```
from fabric import task

@task
def hello():
  print("uptime")
```

Running `fab hello` should yield the expected output.

Source: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1854#issuecomment-414639606

Comment: got the same original error, so tried this - now I get "Tasks must have an initial Context argument" - so off to google that :)

Answer (score -2):

You most likely have to type:

```
fab hello()
```

or

```
$ fab hello
```

Comment: they have already said they tried `fab hello`